# Converting wrapped text to normal using vba

Tags: excel, vba

I need a vba code to convert wrapped text to normal text. Its pain copying to notepad n pasting back.
Thanks in advance.

```
Sub unwrap()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Dim str As String

    For Each char In ActiveSheet.UsedRange

        str = char.Value

        If Trim(Application.Clean(str)) <> str Then
            str = Trim(Application.Clean(str))
            char.Value = str
        End If

    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: [Interesting Read](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: am sorry siddarth i asked coz i was stuck n sry i cant accept your comment. And yes am not posting without giving try thanks.

Comment: `And yes am not posting without giving try thanks` Can you show us what have you tried? Did you read the link I gave in  my last comment?

Comment: mhmm i did n yes i have no time to even research i need immediate solution so i have posted. if u can understand the urgency.

Comment: Can you update the question with the code. It is really difficult reading the code in comments

Comment: oops sorry,yeh i tried with 4 spaces its still coming as comment.

Comment: Great! Now we are heading somewhere :) Reversed the downvote and retracted the close vote.

Comment: Right to begin with, is the text on separate lines and you want them in 1 line?

Comment: with reputation = 1 he may not have edit rights on his post ?!? ... moved code from comment to OP

Comment: k thanks i ll try to change my uploader.

Comment: @MikeD: You don't need reps to edit your own question :)

Comment: @Varshaan: Please see my last comment directed at you. If you have a sample file with few rows populated then that will also expedite the resolution.

Comment: @siddharth ... oops ... 'ts so long ago

Comment: o sure sid i will try to upload the file asap.

Comment: you will not be able to upload it here in stackoverflow but you can do it in any free file uploading sites like www.wikisend.com and then simply share the link here.

Comment: thanks mike and yeh if i use range like for column w it shoots error saying object required.  `For Each char In ActiveSheet.Range("w:w")`

Comment: @siddharth that site is blocked in ma company and i will try to read faq's and follow next time :)

Comment: You can upload it to any other free file loading sites, like dropbox, skydrive etc

Comment: sure @SiddharthRout and my problem is still up. again i am getting wrap text and i have to manually copy to notepad and paste back text.

Comment: Please re-read my last comment. May I see your file????

Comment: aah all the sites mentioned are blocked i just have code which was spaced properly by mike:D

Comment: Ok how does the data look like in the cell. Is it in multilines? and you want to make that one line? Also please you "@" and then my name so that I can get the alerts

Comment: yes @SiddharthRout the cell stored multilined text and i want to make it single lined.

Comment: Check the answer that O just posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Shooting in the Dark**

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim nCalc As Long

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    nCalc = Application.Calculation
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    '~~> Replace this with the actual sheet name
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        .Cells.Replace What:=Chr(160), _
        Replacement:="", _
        LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        MatchCase:=False
    End With

LetsContinue:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = nCalc

    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

Comment: yeyyy it worked thanks guys and sorry for mistakes in postings. spl thanks to @SiddharthRout it worked perfectly :)